# Git hook to detect if fetched repo contains file and stop merge

Tags: git, git-merge, githooks

Although not ideal, our build process leaves our remote git repo in an "out-of-sync" state for a few minutes, where the source code doesn't match the compiled code / DB schema dump, which are committed to git.  We've explored ways to prevent this, but it's not possible to do it in the near future.

We'd like to implement a simple git hook that warns any developer when they've pulled down the repo in this state. It can be done simply by detecting the presence of one or more files. How would we implement a hook that runs on `git merge` (and thereby also `git pull`), which will stop the merge and print a terminal message if any of these files exist in the repo?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to implement a hook which fails a merge in the general case.  There is a `pre-merge-commit` hook, but that only applies when the merge is not a fast forward.  Since most of your developers are probably going to be doing a fast-forward merge into their `master` branch, there's not going to be a way to perform this action.  There are likewise no hooks you can use to abort checkout, in case you were thinking of that.

You could use a server-side hook or CI check to prevent the submission of the code in this bad state, or you could make your local development environment setup or build script fail in this state as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the merges would almost always be fast-forwards. The bad state is "intentionally" as CI then runs the remaining step to update the build artifacts and pushes them to the repo so preventing submission of code sadly won't work.